# recursion method that returns a string after changing every other letter from uppercase or lowercase

Tags: java, string, recursion, methods, return

Change a strings character from every other letter from uppercase to lowercase using recursion and return that string. im trying to expand on my knowledge of recursion i know i could do this without it, but im wondering how you do it this way, this is what i have so far

```
public static String camelCaseRecursive(String w){
     if(w.length()==0) {
      return "";
        }
        
    char sec = 0;
       String returned_str = "";
    char ch = w.charAt(0);
       if (w.length() > 1) {
           sec = w.charAt(1);
       }
       
       ;
    String remaining_str = w.substring(1);
    returned_str = camelCaseRecursive(remaining_str);
        
    if(ch >= 'A' && ch <='Z' && sec >= 'a' && sec <='z'  ) {
           ch = Character.toLowerCase(w.charAt(0));
            
    returned_str = ch+returned_str;
        }
        else if((ch >= 'A' && ch <='Z') && (sec >= 'A' && sec <='Z')  ){
           ch = Character.toLowerCase(w.charAt(0));
           returned_str = ch+returned_str;
        }
        else if((ch >= 'a' && ch <='z')  && returned_str.length() %2 !=0){
          ch = Character.toUpperCase(w.charAt(0));
          returned_str = ch+returned_str;
        }
        else{
           
          returned_str = ch+returned_str;

        }
        
    return returned_str;
}
```

what i expect is

```
input:(Hello World) output:(hElLo wOrLd)
input:(Even) output:(eVeN)
```

what i get is

```
input:(Hello World) output:(hElLo wOrLd)
input:(Even) output:(evEn)
```

i know that the reason i get what i get is because of returned_str.length() %2 !=0 giving odd numbers and if use == it does it for even strings. is there a way to do both or know when to use the appropriate one base on the first call? the thing is i don't know how you would go about alternating between uppercase and lowercase in recursion without having some sort of counter to keep track. Is is possible to set a method that can alternate between upper and lower case, or set a condition that knows when to do so using the length of the string or maybe reading it like a subscript or compare or something?

Comment: @Thiyagu i would perfer not to create any addition methods but i don't mind if there needs to be a change to the method entirely to create a different approach to it or a effective method.

Comment: In this example, it works out that “wOrLd” would start with a lowercase letter regardless, but do you want to camelcase each word or treat it as one continuous string?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to use a private helper method passing additional arguments.

We pass the index of the string to process and to avoid string concatenation, we build the resultant string using a `StringBuilder`.

```
public static String camelCaseRecursive(String s) {
    return camelCaseRecursiveHelper(s, 0, new StringBuilder());
}

private static String camelCaseRecursiveHelper(String s, int i,
                                               StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
    if (i == s.length()) {
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    } else {
        Character curr = s.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetter(curr)) {
            curr = i % 2 == 0
                    ? Character.toLowerCase(curr)
                    : Character.toUpperCase(curr);
        }
        stringBuilder.append(curr);
        return camelCaseRecursiveHelper(s, i + 1, stringBuilder);
    }
}
```

We check if the current index is even or odd and based on that, we do the case-conversion.